# Lockscreen Slideshow

Tags: lock-screen

Can I set my lock screen to run through a set of pictures?  Similar to how bing scrolls through screen savers on a PC.
I have tried to find a setting but nothing works.

Comment: Searching the app store for "lock screen" shows there are a few apps that claim this feature.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no app for this kind of functionality. I also had that wish, but it can't be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a slideshow of bing images, you can easily do so.  Just select Bing for lock screen under Settings > Personalization > Lock screen. They are updated on daily basis. However if you want that **set of pictures** by yourself you'll need some third app easily accessible through Store.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are apps in the store that cycle through wallpapers based on things like the weather, so there could also be apps that go through a directory of images and refreshed the lock screen every x minutes.

It's definitely possible so check out the store and see how you get on.